# Where is CodeMirror.js?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

For the first time I'm trying to use CodeMirror for template edition of my CMS. In the first page of http://codemirror.net there is the following sample:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextarea, {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
</script>
```

But on the GitHub page there isn't any codemirror.js file in the `lib` directory. How should I use this tool?

Comment: Click download on the CodeMirror website's homepage. It's on the red part of the yin-yang symbol.

Comment: Thanks you, It seems I should be waiting for down votes for my post!

Comment: No problem, something about the design of that page makes it really easy to glance past the download link...

Comment: this post helped me too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way to get CodeMirror is to download it. You can get the file links from the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/codemirror

You just have to put the CDN link in the `script` or `link` tag like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css" />
```